# Meaning of max and argmax of a scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I have this `tf-idf` matrix

```
type(dt)  # output: scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
pd.DataFrame(dt.toarray())

# output:

        0          1            2           3        4          5
0   0.000000    0.000000    0.500000    0.500000    0.5    0.50000
1   0.707107    0.707107    0.000000    0.000000    0.0    0.00000
2   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0    0.00000
3   0.000000    0.000000    0.707107    0.707107    0.0    0.00000
4   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0    0.00000
5   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0    0.00000
6   0.577350    0.577350    0.000000    0.000000    0.0    0.57735
7   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0    0.00000
8   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.0    0.00000
9   0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    1.0    0.00000
```

I ran this code to understand the meaning of `max` and `argmax` of the matrix

```
test = np.dot(dt, np.transpose(dt))
test[test > 0.9999] = np.nan
ind = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(test), test.shape)
print('shape of test', test.shape)
print(f'max of test: {test.max()}')
print(f'argmax of test: {np.argmax(test)}')
print('location of max value:', ind)
print('value at the location:', test[ind])
print(pd.DataFrame(test.toarray()))
```

Which produced this output

```
shape of test (10, 10)
max of test: nan
argmax of test: 1
location of max value: (0, 1)
value at the location: 0.0
          0         1    2         3    4    5         6    7    8    9
0       NaN  0.000000  0.0  0.707107  0.0  0.0  0.288675  0.0  0.0  0.5
1  0.000000       NaN  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.816497  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.707107  0.000000  0.0       NaN  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0
5  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0
6  0.288675  0.816497  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0       NaN  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0
8  0.000000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.0
9  0.500000  0.000000  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  0.000000  0.0  0.0  NaN
```

But I couldn't understand the meaning of the output for `max of test: nan`, `argmax of test: 1` and `location of max value: (0, 1)`. I thought the `max of test` and `argmax` should be **0.816497** instead of `nan` and **1** respectively; and the location of the max value should be `(6, 1)` or `(1, 6)` where the value 0.816497 was displayed.

Could someone please explain what the code for `max of test`, `argmax of test` and `location of max value` did?

Answer (score 1):

If `ndarray.max` encounters a "nan", that's what it returns.  That's described in the documentation.   You should look at `np.nanmax`.

`np.argmax` returns the index of the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the documentation. I'm still a bit unclear about the `np.argmax` though. If it returns the indices of the maximum value, that means the location `(0, 1)` referred to the value `0`, which is not the max value of the matrix `test`.